# How Get a list of roles and use them as radiobuttons or dropdown list in register page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to use Account controller and I want to add roles for each user.
Firs of all I want to get all roles from "webpage_role" table in database , then I want to show all expect admin in register page and the User select one of them by Radio button or drop down list and then the rule will give to the user in data base:
My base problem is to get all roles first show them to the users in register page.
this is my account controller:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {

        var allroles = Roles.GetAllRoles(); 
        return View();
    }
```

this would be my register view :

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)         
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>            
       <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.roleName)

            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.roleName, 1, new {style="width:20px" }) simple user <br />
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.roleName, 2, new {style="width:20px" }) agent <br /></li>


    </ol>
```

how I can get a list of roles and with foreach use it in view for radiobutton instead of this static radio buttoms?

Answer (score 0):

Model is something like

```
class UsersModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
class Role
{
    Id { get; set; }
    Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your razor controller should give the model to the view

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var allroles = Roles.GetAllRoles(); 
    var model =  // createUserModel
    return View(model);
}
```

In your razor view you could show the id and name for the role

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.UsersModel>

// rest of your code here.. only example of foreach

@foreach (var role in Model.Roles) 
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Name, m.Id, new {style="width:20px" }) simple user <br />
}
```